# Language specific webcontent in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to implement a static website using Liferay's WCM. I want content to be displayed in user specific/selected language.

I am not sure whether I have to write separate content for each language or is there any way by which Content will get translated to user specific language?

I have tried "Add translation" in web content but it seems to be not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There's no automatic translation to another language. If you choose "Add translation" in the Web Content Editor, you'll have to edit the translated version yourself. Then you can use the user's profile settings or the "Languages" portlet or just the URL to determine the language. If an article is available in the user's language, that version will be shown.

You can try the URL parameters by just adding the language code as the first part of the page. E.g. https://www.liferay.com/community brings you to the default version for your user profile (if you're logged in), while https://www.liferay.com/de/community shows the german (de) version of that site. Every content that is translated to german will show in german, while the content that's not translated will be shown in the default language.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. "Add translation" is working for me now.